# How to set a system-wide proxy on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I'm in a strange position where the `apt-get update` works and can connect to the internet although nothing else works in a Docker container.

I'm not sure if I have put the proxies in the wrong place or I am missing something else.

For the apt-get I add the following to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and it works.

```
Acquire::http::proxy  "http://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80/";
```

Although since also placing the credentials in the correct (I think) pattern / format in `/etc/profile` I cannot get commands such as `curl` or `ping` to work.

Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: You may have to set a system-wide proxy, not only for `apt`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type `env | grep proxy`, if it returns nothing then exporting proxies might help:

```
export https_proxy=https://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80
export http_proxy=http://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80
export ftp_proxy=ftp://user:pass@172.18.*.*:80
```

Comment: yeah, but if I understand correct, it only works for current terminal session

Comment: @Line yes, you are correct. If you want this to work for all terminal sessions, you need to put these commands in your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

If your user's default shell is bash or another Bourne compatible shell, then interactive login shells will read from the global /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/*.sh and /etc/bash.bashrc files. Interactive non-login shells will also read from the global /etc/bash.bashrc file.

Creating a /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh file with the http_proxy, https_proxy, and ftp_proxy environment variables set should make those values available to most programs the next time you log in.

Here is an example proxy.sh file where the http, https, and ftp proxy is the same:

```
export http_proxy=http://my.local.proxy:port
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
```

Some login methods might skip those files so if it doesn't work, you could try putting them in /etc/bash.bashrc so that each new interactive shell you open has those values set.

Comment: _home/user_name/.bashrc_ is also fine (in my case in Ubuntu 19.04)

Answer (score 2):

This will be very simple . I have created a python 3 script for this

[proxy_configuration](https://github.com/nityanandagohain/proxy_configuration.git)

download it and run it . You can set and remove system wide proxy very quickly.

steps:
1) Download in zip and extract it.
2) open terminal and navigate to the folder where you have extracted the file.
3) type the following commands 
   chmod +x proxy.py 
   sudo ./proxy.py

cheers!.